# Making count reset for each word

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my spelling game there is a grid that is populated with words that are hidden from the user. The aim of the game is to spell these words with the aid of a sound and a picture. The user spells a word by clicking the relevant letters onto the grid.

If the user gets a word wrong the word will glow red. If this happens 3 times then the user will be given the opportunity to move onto the next word with the aid of a button that will appear on the 3rd incorrect attempt.

At the moment this works but I have just come across an error by which the incorrect count carries over. For example if the user gets 2 incorrect attempts on one word then gets it right it moves on to the next. It will then only take one incorrect answer on that word for the user to be given the move on option. Basically I need a way for the count to reset every time it moves on to the next word.

This code counts the number of wrong attempts and then after 3 makes the button (".minibutton") visible.

```
    var score = {
    right: 0,
    wrong: 0,
    attempts: 0
};

    score.wrong++;

        if (score.wrong == 3) {

            $(".minibutton").css('visibility', 'visible');
            $('.next').css('visibility', 'visible');
         }
```

A fiddle to help - http://jsfiddle.net/smilburn/7Y7A5/4/ (Sound warning!)

Comment: When the user answers correctly, set score.wrong to 0?

Comment: Your answer worked. If you want a tick post and answer @eakron

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the user answers correctly, set score.wrong to 0.

Edit:

As pointed out, you need to handle the case where the user skips the question after incorrectly answering, so a better place to reset the score.wrong value is when you show a new picture, rather than when they answer correctly.

Comment: that is already handled, the only problem was that the number of wrong answers carried over between questions

Comment: i did some testing and it is not handled, if the user answers 3x incorrect and skips the picture, there is no possibility to skip the next picture because the counter won't get reset properly and the "skip" message never appears.

Comment: I see your point, updated my answer. Not sure why someone downvoted though O.o

Comment: I did, because your answer was wrong, but now that your answer is correct I can feel free to upvote it;)

Answer (score 2):

You need to reset `score.wrong` every time when a new picture is shown regardless if the user answered wrong or correct.

Btw, your code throws some additional errors, you might want to fix them.

> Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'show'

Comment: It didn't work so I put it when a correct answer is made and it worked. As for the errors I will deal with them later, but thanks for the help. @Christoph

Comment: So maybe you can't set it directly there, where I suggested to set it, but you definitely need to reset it after 3 wrong attempts when the new word is created and NOT when the user answers correctly, because it still will carry on, if the user does NOT answer correctly. I didn't had time to figure out in your code exactly where, but basically all that you need is to reset it right after a new word is shown.